# Frequency of tenses

Tags: temps-grammatical, linguistique

French conjugation has many tenses. So if we knew which tenses are used the most, we could learn those tenses first and spend more time practicing them. Is there any corpus-based research about frequency of tenses in formal and informal French?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are a lot of them. Here you can find some sources:

- [*Structure et exploitation de la conjugaison des verbes en français contemporain* - Claire Blanche-Benveniste (2002)](https://www.cairn.info/revue-le-francais-aujourd-hui-2002-4-page-11.htm)
- [*Une description bilingue des temps verbaux :
  étude contrastive en corpus* - Cristina Grisot & Bruno Cartoni (2012)](https://clf.unige.ch/files/1014/4102/7431/5_grisot_cartoni_Nclf30_101-117.pdf)
- [*Pistes pour l’enseignement de la conjugaison* - Suzanne-G. Chartrand (2011)](https://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/en-quete-doutils-pour-sameliorer-en-francais/pistes-pour-lenseignement-de-la-conjugaison/)
- [*Les temps du passé français et leur enseignement* - Emmanuelle Labeau and Pierre Larrivée (2002)](https://books.google.com/books?id=RNg6OhcQL_cC&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=corpus%20fr%C3%A9quences%20de%20l%27utilisation%20des%20temps%20en%20fran%C3%A7ais&source=bl&ots=emAMokZCkf&sig=ACfU3U2ScX2wrsm5P6s12pDB-10IuFaU3g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJhcuZy4DqAhUORDABHY85AecQ6AEwAnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=corpus%20fr%C3%A9quences%20de%20l'utilisation%20des%20temps%20en%20fran%C3%A7ais&f=false)

I did not read all of them but they seem relevant.

To give you a perspective of a native French, as a child, we are taught verbs in **3 groups**:

- Group 1 includes all verbs in -ER such as 'manger', 'chanter', etc.
- Group 2 includes -IR verbs such as 'finir' with the present participle ending in -issant (ending) or with present for we ending in -issons. *We know, from hearing other people talk, which verbs are in this group. 'Courir' is not in this group because we can not say: 'nous courrissons'.*
- The 3rd group includes all the other verbs like 'prendre", "voir", "faire",... as well as -IR verbs whose present participle does not end in -issant. For this group with a beautiful book for that called: **Bescherelle** that you can look through when you don't know the conjugation.

We start to learn conjugation: the *indicatif* (*présent, futur, passé composé, imparfait, ...*), then *conditionnel*, then *subjonctif*.

Why in this order? *Indicatif* is the most common. *Conditionnel* implies a notion of probability (it could happen). *Subjonctif* is for more complex sentences with relatives.

Some tenses are commonly used:

- *présent*
- *passé composé*
- *futur*
- *imparfait* *(Tu faisais quoi ?)*
- *présent du subjonctif* *(Faut que tu **prennes** ton permis)*

The others are mostly used in literature. You can hear some *plus-que-parfait* in formal French. You will never hear *futur antérieur*, *passé antérieur* and *passé simple* in informal French and rarely in formal French (almost never).

The *futur antérieur* and *plus-que-parfait* are less used but nevertheless mainstream: *Tu avais pris quoi ?* / *Tu aurais pris quoi ?* (Thanks to jlliagre in the comments).

Here is something really interesting: most of the people do not use all of the tenses but can clearly understand why we use them and understand the timeline. Those tenses are used a lot in literature and give important details to the action. *Passé simple* means the action is short, whereas the *imparfait* means a long action. *Plus-que-parfait* could mean that the action was before the past action, and so on. They are really important. It's just that in everyday French, we just use a few of them.

For example, this sentence:

> "J'étais parti (plus-que-parfait) quand elle m’appela sur mon téléphone (passé-simple)."

In informal/common French, people could say:

> "Je suis parti (passé-composé) et après elle m'a appelé au téléphone (passé-composé)."

Instead of leveraging the *plus-que-parfait*, we can use *après* to tell that the second action happened after the first one. Obviously the second one is less pretty but both are understandable.

In the end, you can say most of the things with *présent, futur and passé composé* but for the beauty of the language, you can go deeper.

For the *impératif*, you know them because of your parents: *Range ta chambre.*, *Lave-toi les mains*, ...

Comment: The first document linked (Blanche-Benveniste) is a gem. About your answer, in addition to the *présent*, *passé composé* and *futur*, I would add the *imparfait* and the *présent du subjonctif* to the list of commonly used tenses. e.g. *Tu faisais quoi ?* and *Faut que tu prennes ton permis*. The *futur antérieur* and *plus que parfait* are less used but nevertheless mainstream: *Tu avais pris quoi ?* / *Tu aurais pris quoi ?*. Finally, you also miss to list the *impératif*.

Comment: Erm, guys? "Tu aurais pris quoi" is not a futur antérieur, it's a conditionnel passé.